# How can I live stream 360 video on Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, virtual-reality, oculus, 360-virtual-reality

So I was wondering how can we make most out of 360 videos and VR headsets. 
***Task:*** to create a application which can live stream a 360 video and also allows full control over it. 
***Pre-Req:*** what's best camera available in the market for the purpose? 
***Application:*** one of the probable application could be different sensor integration to maximize/manipulate the video. 
***PS:*** I already know there are some video players in unity which allows to play 360 videos but I didn't come across anything that allows live streaming of 360 videos. I know there are some cameras that allows 360 live streaming to YT, FB etc but how can we do the same for unity application. Please share your thoughts and ideas. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to stream to a WebCamTexture(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html). You'll then need to correctly map to a sphere geometry that renders the video correctly, the Skybox texture shader does this:
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/07/27/how-to-integrate-360-video-with-unity/?_ga=2.169592673.1129485550.1533088804-1377740889.1533088804